# Why can't I input any items for my radio button in my PowerApps Canvas application?

Tags: powerapps-canvas

Like the title says, whenever I try to but anything with the brackets ["",""] in my Items field for my Radio button, the whole radio button is staying empty and gives me an error.

I tried changing brackets and using {} instead, as well as ";" instead of "," but nothing helps.

I'm wondering if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: ["Item1","Item2"] is correct syntax. Can you please share any pictures and the error message so we can help?